# Import folder with Multiple CSV's into SSMS w/ out SSIS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, import, csv, bulk

I am wondering what's the best and most effective way to import csv's stored in a local folder into DB w/ in SSMS.

Folder path- C:\Users\ngutierrez\Desktop\Open_Air_Tables

Folder contains about 30 csv files. Each time these csv's are updated I need the DB to reflect the changes.

Comment: Welcome to DBA SE, please see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16076309/import-multiple-csv-files-to-sql-server-from-a-folder

Comment: @kevinwhat - I am pretty new to the space. I copied that code and input my folder path and it didn't seem to work in my instance of SSMS. Wonder what I am doing wrong

Comment: Also, this Folders houses CSV's of many different Objects with different structures. Thus, I would need to extract those tables and load them into a database. I am trying to not have to request SSIS but it seems like that's my only route.